# What does this error means using SwiftMailer via SMTP "554 Too many nonmail command"?

Tags: php, email, smtp, swiftmailer

I am currently using SwiftMailer SMTP to send a large number (around 4000 addresses) of emails using BCC with an application Im developing with PHP, but I keep getting this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Expected response code 250 but got code "554", with message "554 Too many nonmail commands "' in /home/childsur/public_html/plugins/swiftmail/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:386

What does this error means and how can it be rectified?

Thanks in advance

Comment: it's ambiguous, we would need to see the mail logs. it's probably a rejection error because of a poor reputation and what have you

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swiftmailer/rs-GsryK6ds